# Python passing filenames with "/" and "()" to Ghostscript

Tags: python, pdf, path, directory, filenames

I am trying to obtain all the files names in a folder, and then use the same name to save a jpg. When i run this script, everything works. I do not have the luxury to write the file names myself everytime so I am passing in all the file names in the folder pdfs.
Here is the output for the following code.

```
import ghostscript, os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def get_files(path):
    input_files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    return input_files

def pdf2jpeg(pdf_input_path, jpeg_output_path):
    args = ["pdf2jpeg", # actual value doesn't matter
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-sDEVICE=jpeg",
            "-dJPEGQ=95",
            "-r600x600",
            "-sOutputFile=" + jpeg_output_path,
            pdf_input_path]
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_files = get_files("pdfs")
    pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")
    for input_file in input_files:
        input_file_name = str("pdfs/"+str(input_file))
        output_file_name = str('jpgs/'+str(input_file).replace(" ", "_").replace("pdf", "jpg"))#split(".")[0]
        print input_file_name
        print output_file_name
```

As you can see in the main function `pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")`

```
OUTPUT = Copyright (C) 2015 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.18: Some glyphs of the font BAAAAA+ComicSansMS requires a patented True Type interpreter.
##### 37232128 c_void_p(37232128)
```

works fine. Now i want to loop through the imported file list. as you can see i am looping and printing to get the following OUTPUT:

```
##### 34209280 c_void_p(34209280)
pdfs/test1_(5th_copy).pdf
/jpgs/test1_(5th_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1_(copy).pdf
/jpgs/test1_(copy).jpg
pdfs/test1_(4th_copy).pdf
/jpgs/test1_(4th_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1_(3rd_copy).pdf
/jpgs/test1_(3rd_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1_(another_copy).pdf
/jpgs/test1_(another_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1.pdf
/jpgs/test1.jpg
pdfs/test1_(6th_copy).pdf
/jpgs/test1_(6th_copy).jpg
```

When add the following line to my loop,

```
for input_file in input_files:
    input_file_name = str("pdfs/"+str(input_file))
    output_file_name = str('jpgs/'+str(input_file).replace(" ", "_").replace("pdf", "jpg"))#split(".")[0]
    print input_file_name
    print output_file_name
    pdf2jpeg(input_file_name, output_file_name)

# ADDED THIS LINE: pdf2jpeg(input_file_name, output_file_name)
# INSTEAD OF pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")
```

I get this OUTPUT:

```
pdfs/test1 (copy).pdf
jpgs/test1_(copy).jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gsPdf2Jpg.py", line 27, in <module>
    pdf2jpeg(str(input_file_name), str(output_file_name))
  File "gsPdf2Jpg.py", line 17, in pdf2jpeg
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
  File "/home/trackstarz/prohealth/phenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 157, in Ghostscript
    stderr=kw.get('stderr', None))
  File "/home/trackstarz/prohealth/phenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 72, in __init__
    rc = gs.init_with_args(instance, args)
  File "/home/trackstarz/prohealth/phenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 177, in init_with_args
    raise GhostscriptError(rc)
```

How can I pass the correct directory/filename to run the function?
I am using Ubuntu 14.06 python 2.7 and the Ghostscript library

Comment: the parentheses seem to be the problem. Slashes are okay.

Comment: Are you saying you are replacing spaces in actual filenames with underscores? `input_file_name = str("pdfs/"+str(input_file).replace(" ", "_"))` If so, the input files won't exist with that path since they have spaces and not underscores.

Comment: True, I made some corrections but now I don't know the issue.

Comment: @jacobIRR wouldnt the `pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")` Fail since the only difference is that I am passing the desired file name instead of writing it in?